# Separation of concerns in Node.js

Tags: node.js, api, express, frontend, backend

I've been learning Node.js for a couple of weeks. These days I was looking for advice on best practices and came across the concept of "Separation of concerns". I understood (tell me if I'm wrong) that it consists on split the backend and the frontend into two different servers. I've been using template engines such as ejs and pug so far, but I always have these files in the same directory as the rest of the Express server (in a "views" folder). I think there are many ways to separate the frontend and backend, maybe having 2 folders, 1 for the frontend with just simple HTML, CSS, and js files and make AJAX requests to the API, that will be in the other folder, the backend's one.

I'm pretty new in the backend so I hope this question makes sense haha. I'm a bit confused about how backend and frontend connections should work and how I can make a frontend that is independent of the technology used in the backend, so if you know books or resources in general about this, tell me.

Comment: "*[Separation of concerns] consists on split the backend and the frontend in two different servers*" not at all. Very simply put it's a principle to not lump everything together. *How* you separate the concerns can differ. You can split code that interacts with the database from code that creates dropdowns in the UI. Whether these are in different files, different sub-modules, different services, or different applications entirely is not something SoC will mandate. Just that these are two different areas of concerns, so they should be separated.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack

Best practices are different from developer to another and they are tend to be evolving.. so that is what i’m doing :

1 - Separate Directory for fronted and backendusing node proxy .
2- src Folder that contains ( for backend ) views , routes and controllers … etc .

Answer (score 0):

Separation of concerns is the idea that each module or layer in an application should only be responsible for one thing and should not contain code that deals with other things.

Separating concerns reduces code complexity by breaking a large application down into many smaller units of encapsulated functionality.